# Naming matrix columns within a nested loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to produce a matrix using an R loop (for other reasons I don't want to use vectors in this case, which would be amenable to `outer()`), such that the columns came labeled with the pair `i`, `j` corresponding to the iterations of the loop. For instance, `(1,3)`.

I'm used to starting a vector outside the loop with `NA` or `0` assigned to it. I know that determining the dimensions ahead of time is more efficient. But I don't want to have to determine the dimensions in more complex problems of this type, and within the loop I don't know how to fill in the vector. Usually I would code it as `vector[i] <- new value to add`, but here I am juggling two indexes, `i` and `j`, and if I index it like `vector[i,j] <- new value to add` I believe R gets confused thinking of a matrix.

Here is the non-working code:

```
x1=c(1,4,2,5,6)
x2=c(5,3,7,7,8)
data=data.frame(x1,x2)
data=as.matrix(data)
n = 6 # polynomial degree

for(i in 1:n){
  for(j in 0:n){
    data = cbind(data,data[,1]^(i-j) * data[,2]^j)
    colnames(data) = paste("(",i,",",j,")")
  }
}

data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to change

```
colnames(data) = paste("(",i,",",j,")")
```

to

```
colnames(data)[ncol(data)] = paste("(",i,",",j,")")
```

cause you want to change only last column (the one recently added).